# Bootstrap-select not working inside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am implementing this [selectpicker](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) for my website. I encountered an issue that an element that has the `selectpicker` class it doesn't show on my DOM.

here is the code

```
<div id="modal-container"  class="modal fade hidden-print" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Experience</h4>
    </div>

        <div id="addExperience" class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <select class="user-form selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true">
                                        <option>A</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

please help me get in track with my development.

Thanks!

Comment: looks ok to me https://plnkr.co/edit/HHxNkpbUITBQJBSHaJQ8?p=preview

Comment: I don't know why its not showing on my end. i always get this css property to my `select.selectpicker{ display: none !important;` do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Could you create a plunker with your complete code ? Will have a look

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/grjPhsHCZC8BPRHcdv4t?p=preview

Answer (score 8):

You have to reinitialize your Bootstrap-Select (.selectpicker) after loading your modal. The reason why this is happening is, your modal is a newly created element and your selectpicker is not yet initialized on it.

Here's my code:

```
// Create
$(document).on('click', '.add', function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'suppliers/create',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            modal.find('.modal-title').html(data.title);
            modal.find('.modal-body').html(data.body);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        }
    });
    modal.modal('show');
});
```

Thanks very much to [Cerlin Boss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003182/cerlin-boss) for this solution!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the below required resources in your plunker example

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/i18n/defaults-en_US.js"></script>
```

and things work fine :)

Let me know in case the actual code still differs from the plunker.

Example : https://plnkr.co/edit/4gJBAu3NKUQp1HMUbrK9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options;

**Firstly** add this options in your select tag;

```
<select ... data-container="body"> ... </select>
```

source: [docs](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#container)

**Secondly** write this code for override "overtflow" property

```
.modal-content{
    overflow: unset;
}
```